# Why is surface size on an iPhone5 wrong?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, screen, retina-display

I'm using cocos2d v2.0.0 with simulator 6.1.

When I compile a project in iPhone5 simulator in xcode, the surface size is

> cocos2d: surface size: 1136x640

The application works correctly, fitting to screen borders 1136x640, but when I run application on a iPhone5 Device, I get

> cocos2d: surface size: 960x640

The image no longer covers the full screen.

What is the problem?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to make sure and have you have a 4 inch launch image defined in your project.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use [cocos2d 2.1](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/archives/2039)

and use methods to get screen size:

```
[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSize];

[[CCDirector sharedDirector] winSizeInPixels];
```

Comment: problem is not getting the winSize, it doesn't get correct device size in iPhone. On simulator, it's ok. but on device its getting wrong sizes.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely the screenshot you provided for iPhone 5 (Default-568@2x.png) somehow doesn't copy to the device. Possible reasons:
- Bad png format.
- Bad name (default-568@2x.png vs Default-568@2x.png). Simulator is case sensitive.
- Not in the copy files target in the project settings. It might have already copied on the simulator at a certain point but right now it's not copying into the project.

Hope this helps.